# accordion with image as on off button

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I have an example of code, it's for accordion

right here

http://jsfiddle.net/hDRMP/18/

The problem is,

I want to change the Lorem/Ipsum into an image.
So it will be like on off button,
image1 click, accordion open + image1 change into image2.
image2 click, accordion close + image2 change into image1

I have made some modification thorugh it.

CSS

```
.accordionButton a{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    background:url(image1.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
.on{
    background:url(image2.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    float: left;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
.over{
    background:url(image1.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    float: left;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
```

anyone can help?
Thanks...

Comment: I don't see why your example would not work. Everything looks good, just add images.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by removing the `a` element from your `accordionButton` container completely and using background images as you showed in your example. Then you simply need to add the proper CSS styles.

HTML

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordionButton"></div>
    <div class="accordionContent">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="accordionButton"></div>
    <div class="accordionContent">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.accordionButton, .accordionContent {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.accordionButton {
    width: 136px; /* height of the image used */
    height: 23px; /* width of the image used */
    margin: 0 auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(accordionbutton.png) no-repeat;
}
.accordionButton.over,
.accordionButton.on.over {
    background: url(accordionbutton_hover.png) no-repeat;
}
.accordionButton.on {
    background: url(accordionbutton_active.png) no-repeat;
}
```

**Suggestion:** For more responsive interaction, I would recommend using a [sprite sheet](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/css-sprite-sheets-best-practices-tools-and-helpful-applications/) for the button state images so that there is not a noticeable load transition when you change states for the first time.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BWMXx/2/)